# Expected value in a coin flip

Tags: probability, statistics

I was reading a book of introduction to Probability and Statistics and it had only a brief introduction to expected value and variance. So I got lost in the follow exercise:

> A fair coin is flipped independently until the first head occurs. Let X be the random variable that counts the number of tosses before the occurrence of a head one. Find E(X) and Var(X).

First of all, I tried to write down potential sequences:

H (Head in the first flip)

TH (Head in the second flip)

TTH

TTTH

and it goes on...

So $E[X]$ could be:

$$E[X]=0\cdot \frac12 + 1\cdot \frac14 + 2\cdot\frac18 + 3\cdot\frac1{16}... \rightarrow 1$$

Is that right? I'm not sure if I should use xi as the total numbers of tosses or the numbers of tosses before getting a head.

And for the $Var(X)$, I don't really know how to proceed, since I just had examples using the mean, which I don't think is the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track.

> I'm not sure if I should use xi as the total numbers of tosses or the numbers of tosses before getting a head.

Reasonable doubt. [Both alternatives are possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution). In this case, ("number of tosses before the occurrence of a head") your choice seems ok.

To compute the variance, you can use

$$\sigma^2= E[X - \mu]^2 = E[X^2] - \mu ^2$$

where $\sigma^2$ is the variance and $\mu=E[X]$ is the mean.

Comment: Ok, that's pretty good. Finishing the exercise: Var(X)=E[X^2]-E[X].   E[X^2] = 0.1/2 + 1.1/4 + 4.1/8 + 9.1/16 + 16.1/32 + ... ~ 3.   Var(X)=3-1=2.   That's it? (sorry for the notations, i'm not sure how to use them here.)

Comment: First, you a missing the square in  $Var(X)=E[X^2]-E[X]$

Comment: Second, I'm not sure how you evaluated the sum,  (the$ \sim 3$ should not be an approximation but an exact result) but the result seems fine.

Comment: Alright, I got it. Thank you so much, appreciate your help.